# How to provide input to a java program via a .sh script file

Tags: java, bash, unix

I have 3 Java programs that needs to run on UNIX. So I will open up a terminal window each time to run each Java program. But the input to any one of them is to be provided at another terminal window via executing a .sh file.

i.e. All the 3 Java programs need to expect input from the standard input which is to be provided via another terminal.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: why don't you run it from the script, so that you can pass whatever input it needs

Comment: actually its part of a project and the test cases are in the form of .sh files which would be tested out by a grader, so thus...

Comment: Change test cases to accommodate changes. That will be easier or try Jon's comment

Comment: Why not write the output of the shell script to a file, and then just redirect stdin from that file three times? `foo.sh > foo_results.txt && java Bar < foo_results.txt && java Baz < foo_results.txt && java Qux < foo_results.txt`

Comment: @JonSkeet as I have mentioned above, my grader will be running those scripts as test cases. what u have said is totally feasible, but i won't be allowed to do that..

Comment: It's *really* unclear what you're asking, to be honest. Why can't the grader run the scripts and store the output in a file? Or run the scripts and just pipe the result straight to the Java programs? You can't just fetch the output of an unrelated process.

Comment: You can open socket in java that will read input from terminal and write user input there. Another java can read from this socket.

Comment: @LeosLiterak sorry forgot to mention, no socket or multithreading..
the project is to implement DVMRP using plain old files.

Comment: Then write user input to file in one process and read it back in the other. Something like user input journal.

Comment: Shall one run of a Java program be able to get input from multiple successive shell script runs?